# Selected value not showing on Dropdown using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Javascript code is showing below and my problem is when I click this button `editcpumonbtn`  more than three times, the dropdown list does not come up with selected attr but when I inspect the html code option selected attr is applied.

Dropdown list not showing the selected value it freezes.

```
 $(".editcpumonbtn").on('click', function(e) {
   var cmpid = $.trim($(this).attr("data-comp"));
    $("#EditMonandCpuCompanyDropdown > option").each(function() {
        //alert(this.text + ' ' + this.value);
        if ($.trim(this.value) == cmpid) {
            $(this).attr('selected', true);
        } else {
            $(this).attr('selected', false);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors in console window??

Comment: Can you please show some HTML as a verifiable snippet that reflects your issue?

Comment: Does it work better if you use `prop()` instead of `attr()`? Also note that today's releases (1.12.2 and 2.2.2) fix a bug in IE when setting the `selected` property of `<option>` elements. You might be impacted by it.

Comment: @Reddy not getting any errors

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I insert my HTML Code

Comment: @Rimaz I can't see it. But I've added also some code.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Thnks but i am using jquery-1.11.3 bit difficult to upgrade

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("[data-comp]").on('click', function(e) {
  
  // e.preventDefault(); // uncomment if <a> elements
  
  var cmpid = $.trim( $(this).data("comp") );
  
  $("#EditMonandCpuCompanyDropdown > option").prop("selected", function(){
    return $.trim(this.value) == cmpid;
  });

  // $("#EditMonandCpuCompanyDropdown").change(); // Eventually. But I see no issue

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button data-comp="A">A</button>
<button data-comp="B">B</button>
<button data-comp="C">C</button>

<select id="EditMonandCpuCompanyDropdown">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me.. Thanks everyone for the best support

```
$("#EditMonandCpuCompanyDropdown").val(cmpid);
```